# Can I use hawaii state in my game commercially?

Tags: game-design, graphics, copyright, graphics-design, commercial

I want to make game more realistic, for that I need a state . So, I decided to take hawaii state, as it can be seen through google maps with street view, 3d view and much more and will help me a lot for making realistic game. So, my simple question is that can I use the whole hawaii state [whole means everthing like clone/duplicate] in my game commercially.

Comment: What do you mean by "clone/duplicate"? Do you mean from Google Maps? If so, then no, their maps are copyrighted. (They paid a lot of money to the satellite company to take those pictures!) If you mean something else, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be better for the Stackoverflow Lawyer's site? Anyway you can use the Hawaii state in your game. As long as you don't use anything from Google maps in your game. You are perfectly fine to create a level/game based around Hawaii because Google doesn't own the rights to Hawaii.

Just make sure you don't use anything from Google maps. Also, to be safe don't clone the buildings. For example don't have the same hardware store with the same name in your game that is in Hawaii. Your making profit from the hardware store.